# Using os.walk to read multiple input files, and GetMessage progress update messages

Tags: python, arcpy, csv

I couldn't quite find the solution to this question, so here we go. I am writing a script that will read data from a CSV file, and I want to automate the code to repeat and read through through several CSV files in one folder. I am trying to use os.walk, but encounter errors.

Questions: 
1. How do I use os.walk correctly? 
2. What is the best way to plug in updates on progress as it goes through the input CSV files?

The first part of the script, where I need to implement os.walk, is below:

```py
import sys
import os
import arcpy
import csv
from arcpy import env

## Set overwrite 
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
print arcpy.env.overwriteOutput

## Set workspace 
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Home\\directory\\"
workspace = "C:\\Home\\directory\\"
print workspace

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\Home\\directory\\CSV\\'):  
    print root, dirs, files
    ## Directory where I'm keeping the CSVs
    full_path = os.path.join(root, files)       

    rows = csv.DictReader(open(full_path, "rb"))
    if os.path.exists(outpath)==False:
         os.mkdir(outpath)

    for row in rows: # here begin reading through the CSV for the rest of the script
```

Comment: Error message here is: TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list"

Comment: Thank you for making this more readable Nathan, I'm still learning how to post elegantly to StackExchange.

Comment: Where in the script is the error being thrown?

Comment: Script does 'print workspace' and then throws error at: for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\Home\\directory\\CSV\\")

Comment: The Salty Crane has some good Python examples. Here's one for os.walk: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/03/python-oswalk-example/

Comment: Please just let me get this settled and I'll be happy to move it to StackOverflow.

Comment: I missed your second question about reporting progress, that is on-topic, but should be asked as a separate question (avoid asking multiple questions in the same post if you can help it).

Answer (score 4):

Oh, I just saw your problem. You are joining the entire list `files` to create your `full_path` variable. If you don't need to dig down into subdirectories where your csv files are located I might use the `glob` module. I've also used the rawstring character `r`; this little guy is very helpful in that it will allow you to copy and paste your paths without having to add another backslash for each directory or change them to forward slashes:

```py
import sys
import os
import arcpy
import csv
from arcpy import env
import glob

## Set overwrite 
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
print arcpy.env.overwriteOutput

## Set workspace 
workspace = r"C:\Home\directory"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
csv_dir = os.path.join(workspace,'CSV')

print workspace

csvList = glob.glob(os.path.join(csv_dir,'*.csv'))
csvNameList = []
for full_path in csvList:

    ## Append csv file name to list
    csvNameList.append(os.path.basename(full_path))

    ## Directory where I'm keeping the CSVs
    arcpy.AddMessage(full_path)       

    rows = csv.DictReader(open(full_path, "rb"))
    if os.path.exists(outpath)==False:
         os.mkdir(outpath)

    for row in rows: # here begin reading through the CSV for the rest of the script
```

To answer the second part of your question, use the `arcpy.AddMessage(csv_name)` function to print the name of the csv file to the tool progress screen (if you are using this in a script tool).

Comment: Thank you for responding and good tips. This seems to be working, except that later on in the script, when the CSVfilename is used to name outputs, it retains the full directory, so that csv_name = "C:\\home\\directory\\csvfilename.csv" instead of just "csvfilename.csv". Is this result due to "csv_dir = os.path.join(workspace, 'CSV') or csvList = glob.glob(os.path.join(csv_dir, '*.csv')) ?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that the glob module will return the full path for each file. I've updated the answer to reflect this and also added `csvNamesList` so that you can later refer to the names of the files without the full path.

Comment: Awesome I'll give this a shot and let you know how it goes. This is really great so far and I really appreciate it.

Comment: Okay we are getting closer. However when I run the script, there is still an error. The CSV file name comes up as [] instead of the name of the file itself.....yerg.

Comment: What is the error and which line is causing it? Is the csv name you're trying to use from `csvNameList`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7911/discussion-between-jason-and-sharonb)

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to Jason's answer if you wanted to stick with os.walk then I normally do the following to find CSV files and then work with them

```
fileList = []
count = 0

directorypath = "C:\Home\directory\CSV"

for dirname, dirnames, filesnames in os.walk(directorypath):
    for filename in filenames:
       if filename.endswith(".csv"):
          fileList.append(filename)
          count = count + 1
```

That way you can just use the fileList to work on

Comment: Thankyou - this is another great option... I had tried this initially but couldn't get it to work. I may return to this if the Glob module still fails me.

Comment: Hi tjmgis, I'm following up to thank you again for the bit of script here - I was able to use it successfully for a few pieces of code for other projects, and it's been very helpful. Cheers!